# How can I sort this JSON data?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, json

How can I sort this JSON data?

Hello,

I am curling a web service and I get this output as JSON using curl and jq. How can I sort the list by percentage, ascending or descending?

```
{
 "result": {
  "binance:adabnb": {
  "price": {
    "last": 0.00724,
    "high": 0.00749,
    "low": 0.00707,
    "change": {
      "percentage": 0,
      "absolute": 0
    }
  },
  "volume": 2706796.2,
  "volumeQuote": 19759.382062
},
"binance:adabtc": {
  "price": {
    "last": 1.213e-05,
    "high": 1.234e-05,
    "low": 1.158e-05,
    "change": {
      "percentage": 0.0341006,
      "absolute": 4e-07
    }
  },
  "volume": 121339053,
  "volumeQuote": 1450.07483142
},
"binance:adaeth": {
  "price": {
    "last": 0.00035813,
    "high": 0.00036636,
    "low": 0.00033522,
    "change": {
      "percentage": 0.059399497,
      "absolute": 2.008e-05
    }
  },
  "volume": 16676148,
  "volumeQuote": 5899.18121885
},
"binance:adatusd": {
  "price": {
    "last": 0.04367,
    "high": 0.04442,
    "low": 0.04141,
    "change": {
      "percentage": 0.022237828,
      "absolute": 0.00095
    }
  },
  "volume": 13075458.7,
  "volumeQuote": 563437.821146
},
"binance:adausdt": {
  "price": {
    "last": 0.04352,
    "high": 0.04407,
    "low": 0.04101,
    "change": {
      "percentage": 0.02859844,
      "absolute": 0.00121
    }
```

Vesa

Comment: Did you try the `sort_by` function of `jq`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but I couldn't find the exact formula.

Comment: Please edit your question with what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking to preserve the same JSON structure and sort the records (within the "result") then obviously it's impossible, because top-label "result" is a JSON object: within objects you don't have a control over the order of JSON elements. it's only possible to do with JSON arrays (arrays could be re-shuffled).

However, if you're looking just to dump the individual records like "binance:adaeth" all of them sorted by "percentage", it's achievable with jtc (an alternative unix utility to jq).

assuming your json is in file.json do this:

```
bash $ cat file.json | jtc -w'<percentage>l: [-3]' -r -l | sort -k10
"binance:adabnb": { "price": { "change": { "absolute": 0, "percentage": 0 }, "high": 0.00749, "last": 0.00724, "low": 0.00707 }, "volume": 2706796.2, "volumeQuote": 19759.382062 }
"binance:adatusd": { "price": { "change": { "absolute": 0.00095, "percentage": 0.022237828 }, "high": 0.04442, "last": 0.04367, "low": 0.04141 }, "volume": 13075458.7, "volumeQuote": 563437.821146 }
"binance:adabtc": { "price": { "change": { "absolute": 4e-07, "percentage": 0.0341006 }, "high": 1.234e-05, "last": 1.213e-05, "low": 1.158e-05 }, "volume": 121339053, "volumeQuote": 1450.07483142 }
"binance:adaeth": { "price": { "change": { "absolute": 2.008e-05, "percentage": 0.059399497 }, "high": 0.00036636, "last": 0.00035813, "low": 0.00033522 }, "volume": 16676148, "volumeQuote": 5899.18121885 }
bash $
```

PS.
you can find my jtc utility on a github.com, or just google up by keywords `jtc` and `json`